# Why local variables do not match all zero condition?

Tags: c

I am experimenting on a very low level with some C coding. This is not an actual problem, because the program works as I wish, but could someone explain to me how the following condition in the while-loop is evaluated?

I read that int variables without any given value equal to zero? Then 0+0 should be zero? But the program enters the while-loop anyway...

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int randomNumber1;
    int randomNumber2;
    int answer;

    while (randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 != answer) {

        randomNumber1 = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        randomNumber2 = (rand() % 100) + 1;

        printf("\nWhat is %i + %i= ", randomNumber1, randomNumber2);
        scanf("%i,", &answer);

        if (randomNumber1 + randomNumber2 == answer) {
            printf("Very Good\n");
        } else {
            printf("Wrong answer.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Weeeee undefined behaviour

Comment: Those variables are initially not zero. You're reading random memory; it's UB.

Comment: What would you expect uninitialized variables to contain other than random data? They don't assign themselves values on their own, because they're lazy. Programmers have to do it for them. And if you learn now how to use a debugger, you could have inspected them yourself and seen that they didn't contain zero, and that the loop was correctly entered. Using a debugger is an essential tool for a programmer, and it's never too early to start learning how to use it.

Comment: What @KenWhite says above, seconded.  If you cannot debug, you cannot program computers.

Comment: "I read that int variables without any given value equal to zero" - Where did you read this?  If it's from a book/website, stopping using that book/website!

Comment: Where does it say they're equal to zero?

Answer (score 1):

Variables in C are (typically) not given values when you don't initialize them.

The reason your code runs is because you have garbage values in those addresses.

Print out the variables and you'll see. You HAVE to initialize variables in C.

Comment: I believe non-automatic variables (*e.g.*, globals) are initialized to zero (if not otherwise initialized).  But automatic (stack) variables are not.

Comment: You mean variables are typically not given values upon NOT being initialized

Comment: I fixed the verbiage.

Comment: @HaskellMcRavin: I'm afraid you are incorrect: uninitialized global variables are initialized to the zero of their kind.

Answer (score 1):

When you declared the integers they took garbage value; this is happens because they're of the "auto" storage class.
If you had declared them outside of main function or with `static` keyword it would be 0 (`extern` and `static` storage class respectively).

Answer (score 1):

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>     unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is
>     initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding
>     is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named
>     member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any
>     padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> <sub>C.2011§6.7.9¶10</sub>

Thus, your function local variables have indeterminate value. If the variables were made `static` or `_Thread_local` or were global (and thus have static storage duration), then they would have been zero initialized.